# RSpec Rails Controller test fails with ActionController::UnknownFormat

Tags: controller, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I have a controller spec defined as

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe Api::V1::StudentsController, type: :request do

  context ".show" do
    let!(:test_portfolio) {
      Portfolio.create(
        slug: "some-portfolio",
        portfolio_type: "abc123",
      )
    }
    let(:params) { ActionController::Parameters.new(slug: "some-portfolio") }

    describe "It finds a portfolio for the slug" do
      it "finds the portfolio" do
        get "/api/v1/students/some-portfolio"
        expect(response.status).to eq(200)
      end
    end
  end
```

The corresponding controller has a `show` action defined as

```
      def show
        student = Portfolio.find(params[:slug])

        respond_to do |format|
          format.json do
            render json: student
          end
        end
      end
```

The test successfully finds the `student` record in the controller, but fails on the `respond_to` line with the message

`ActionController::UnknownFormat: ActionController::UnknownFormat`

Could I have prevented this response in my controller spec, or is my `rails_helper` file to blame?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I managed to define a set of success- and failing tests. Here are some of my changes:

My controller spec, as given above, is correct but the following is better.

```
describe "It finds a portfolio for the slug" do
  before do
    get "/api/v1/students/some-portfolio"
  end

  it "finds the portfolio" do
    expect(response).to be_successful
  end

  it "renders the correct details" do
    response_details = JSON.parse(response.body)
    expect(response_details).to match(/whatever you expect/)
    # more expectations
  end
end
```

I also made an important correction to my Controller action:

```
def show
  student = Portfolio.find(params[:slug])

  render json: offering, status: 200
end
```